# How to make two turtles in one patch both visible?

Tags: netlogo

I have two turtles - seller and buyer in one patch, and they have shape `"face happy"`.
But on interface when I run setup if there are two turtles in one patch i can see only one of them.
my question is, how can i code it so that to see both of them. if its not possible at least to see in some patches one agent in others another one.

and here is my code:

```
ask sellers
         [move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]] 

  ask buyers
         [move-to one-of patches with [not any? buyers-here]] 
    ask buyers [if any? sellers-here [set shape "face happy"]]
  ask buyers [if not any? sellers-here [set shape "face sad"]]
  ask buyers [if any? sellers-here [set color 67]]
  ask sellers [if any? buyers-here [set shape "face happy"]]
  ask sellers [if not any? buyers-here [set shape "face sad"]]
  ask sellers [if any? buyers-here [set color 137]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that you can actually tell if both are present from your face and color cues. If you want to see both, you will need to set transparent colors, or offset the locations, or both.  E.g.,

```
ask buyers [
  move-to one-of patches with [not any? buyers-here]
  ifelse (any? sellers-here) [
    set shape "face happy"
    set color [255 0 0 125]
    fd 0.45
  ][
    set shape "face sad"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Even starting from a patch center, `fd 0.5` might take the turtle to a different patch. I'd suggest a smaller value.

Comment: If headings are random that should be almost impossible, but good point.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming patches with two turtles at the center of patch:

```
 to spread-out   
   ask patches with [count turtles-here = 2]
    [ask one-of turtles-here [
        fd .25 
        ask one-of other turtles-here [face myself fd -0.25]]]
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to make one kind of turtle smaller than the other, and make sure that the smaller one is always on top.  For example, if you use `"circle"` for shape for both buyers and sellers, you can `set size 0.4` for sellers.  Then either move sellers after you move buyers, or do something to cause each seller to be displayed after the buyer on the same patch is displayed.  If you set a display property such as color, shape, or size for all sellers after all of the turtles have moved, that should cause the sellers to appear on top of the buyers.

Another option, if your turtles are smaller than patches, would be to use the patch color to convey information.  For example, you could change the patch color whenever there are two turtles on the same patch.  Or you could make sure that one kind of turtle is always on top (buyer, for example), and always set the patch color to a special value whenever there is a seller on the patch (even when there's no buyer present).